# Tensorflow: U-net regression with single pixel per image data

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

It appears that TensorFlow can be integrated effectively with Google Earth Engine to predict a continuous response using U-net regression (example [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/earthengine-api/blob/master/python/examples/ipynb/UNET_regression_demo.ipynb#scrollTo=psz7wJKalaoj)).

In [this example](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/earthengine-api/blob/master/python/examples/ipynb/UNET_regression_demo.ipynb#scrollTo=psz7wJKalaoj), the response ( the "ground data") is sampled from a satellite image, where every pixel is associated with a value.

In reality, ground data is often made up of single geo-tagged points where the response is collected (for example, bare ground cover in percent at 100 30x30m points spanning a certain area). In the U-net model, this would mean a single pixel containing a value, surrounded by unknown pixels for the response. The predictor values would be band values at those pixels, for example from Landsat composite images.

#### Question

How would you deal with these unknown pixels in the response for a TensorFlow U-net regression? Is it as simple as adding a masking layer telling the model with pixels are unknown? If so, how would you implement that practically?